Docker CMD command behaving differently to local development
I am quite new to Docker and Azure, but when I deploy my container to container instances, the start-up command just doesn't seem to work; I don't know why. I receive no logs back from the Azure container.
Docker file
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# set default java environment variable
ENV JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR=8 \
    JAVA_VERSION_MINOR=111 \
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm \
    PATH=${PATH}:/usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm/bin/

RUN apt-get update && \ 
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt install openjdk-11-jdk -yq && \
    apt install openjdk-17-jdk -yq 

RUN apt-get update && \ 
    apt install openjdk-8-jdk -yq && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 /usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm && \
    apt-get clean all

# Check Java version
RUN java -version && \
    javac -version

# Install linux packages
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -qq -y install software-properties-common git curl build-essential subversion perl wget unzip vim bc 

RUN apt-get install maven -yq

# Setup Apache Maven
ENV MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx2048m"

# Check Maven version
RUN mvn -version

# Install Python
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3.9 python3.9-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel gcc
RUN python3.9 -m pip install pip --upgrade

RUN echo 'alias python=python3.9' >> /root/.bashrc

# RUN apt-get install pkg-config
# RUN apt-get install libcairo2-dev -yq

# RUN pip install argparse
# RUN pip freeze > requirements.txt
# RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /root
COPY ./MOSALLISA-Testing /root/framework

ENV FRAMEWORK_HOME="/root/framework"
# COPY ../vimrc .vimrc
ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"
ENV TMP_DIR="/tmp"

ENV PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8

# install Maven 3.8.1
RUN wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.8.1/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.1-bin.tar.gz -P /tmp 
RUN tar -xzvf /tmp/apache-maven-3.8.1-bin.tar.gz -C /opt

# install Maven 3.8.6
RUN wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.8.6/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.tar.gz -P /tmp
RUN tar -xzvf /tmp/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.tar.gz -C /opt

# install gradle
RUN git config --global --add safe.directory '*'

# install python libraries
# COPY ../requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN python3.9 -m pip install --only-binary :all: numpy==1.21.4
RUN python3.9 -m pip install -r framework/Docker/requirements.txt

# non GHRB dependancies 
RUN pip install azure-storage-blob
RUN pip install python-dotenv


ENV EVOSUITE="/root/framework/MOSAllisaJars/evosuite-1.2.0.jar"
RUN echo "EVOSUITE during build: $EVOSUITE"
RUN echo 'alias evosuite="java -jar $EVOSUITE"' >> /root/.bashrc 

WORKDIR /root/framework

#This command is failing in Azure
CMD ["python3.9", "/root/framework/execute_results_testing.py"]



Start Container instance bash file
REPOS=("sslcontext-kickstart")

for i in "${!REPOS[@]}"; do
  az container create \
    --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
    --name "mosalisa-t$i" \
    --image $IMAGE \
    --dns-name-label "mosallisat$i" \
    --environment-variables TEST_VERSION="REGRESSION_EVOSUITE" \
                            MOSALLISA_CONFIG="NORMAL" \
                            REPO="${REPOS[$i]}" \
                            AZ_STRGE_CONN_STR="$AZ_STRGE_CONN_STR" \
    --registry-username $REGISTRY_USERNAME \
    --registry-password $REGISTRY_PASSWORD \
    --memory $MEMORY
done

Local Start Container file
containername=$1

if [ -z "$containername" ]; then
    containername="mosallisa_framework"
fi

docker ps -aq --filter "name=$containername" | grep -q . && docker stop $containername && docker rm $containername

docker run -dt --name $containername -v $(pwd):/root/framework \
    -e TEST_VERSION="REGRESSION_EVOSUITE" \
    -e MOSALLISA_CONFIG="NORMAL" \
    -e REPO="sslcontext-kickstart" \
    -e AZ_STRGE_CONN_STR="$AZ_STRGE_CONN_STR" \
    mosallisa_framework:latest

# Execute bash inside the running container

I have tried running it locally, and it works as expected and produces logs. I also have tried mannually logging to a file during start up, the azure container starts the command but the python file dosnt output anything, the locally run version also was able to output to the log file. I went into the container manually and ran the same command, and it worked fine.

Are you running into Why doesn't Python app print anything when run in a detached docker container?  (It seems like there are a lot of extra irrelevant tools in your Dockerfile – how does your Python script use Java, with two different versions of Maven?  Can you trim this setup down to a [mcve]?)

Hello, this is a testing framework for a Java app I have developed; I have to run my application on a lot of reports, which are built using different Java and Maven versions. Your solution helped me debug, turns out there was nothing wrong with my code. However, azure kept restarting my container. Hence, my output files would be erased, does azure, by default, restart containers when they execute? Thanls

It is restarting because script file is being executed and all the process is completed, then container stops then it restarts for new process. try adding tail -f /dev/null in your shell script file.

I agree with @Vivek Vaibhav Shandilya's comment.

In a Docker container, when the main script finishes, the container stops. This can cause the container to restart in a loop.
To stop this from happening, we need to keep the container running even after the script is complete.
I've added this command tail -f /dev/null to your code at the end as shown below.

CMD ["python3.9", "/root/framework/execute_results_testing.py", "&&", "tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]


Thanks to @kodekloud for clear explanation, I've referred this doc for better understanding about how to keep the docker container running.
You can add the command to your Dockerfile or shell script, as shown below.

Start .sh:
echo  "Executing Python script..."
python3.9  /root/framework/execute_results_testing.py  
echo  "Python script finished. Keeping container alive..."
tail  -f  /dev/null

Local logs:

After making the above changes, my container successfully stays alive without restarting.
Logs from the Azure Container Instance:

